# Create Map to avoid Query in For Loop

Tags: apex, soql, map, governorlimits

How can I create a Map for such situation - to write my Query outside of For loop and avoid getting caught into "Too many SOQL error :101 "

```
for(ChildRelationship child : childRecords) {
//Loop through and get counts of child records on parent record
 String query = 'select count() from ' + child.getObjectName() + ' where ' + child.getFieldName() + '= \'' + sourceId + '\'';

            Integer countValue = Database.countQuery(query);
            child.setRecordAmount(countValue);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand you, Can you explain your problem more?

Comment: Post additional code to provide context.  setRecordAmount() does not appear to be a property of Schema.ChildRelationship class.  Did you define your own ChildRelationship class?

Comment: If a parent object can have more than 100 child relationships you are going to have a problem here. Note that you can query from a parent up to 5 child relationships per SOQL thus giving you 100 * 5 = 500 possible counts. This problem might be better suited to a pagination example where you let the user page through the first 20 relationships before fetching the next 20, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ChildRelationship is always of the same type, you can create a function to run through 'childRecords' and get the data you want (count and objectName, for example, are simple to get with .size() and the name you already have in your hands).

Also, I don't see in your code where you get that 'sourceId' var, so you can pass it as argument for a function to do this query for you. In the end you will have a function to get the information from the first list, and pass it to another function that has this query inside.

This way you won't even need a Map. Also I don't see why you would need a map for this anyway.